# Organizing a large c++ system in Sun Studio (NetBeans)

Tags: c++, netbeans, sun, sunstudio

My group is maintaining a c++ system that includes multiple executables and many static libraries. It was developed without a contemporary ide, i.e. with emacs. We'd like to start using Sun Studio (NetBeans).
Is there a resource describing how to organize a large set of projects within Sun Studio?
In a previous program using VisualStudio all of our 'projects' were part of a single 'solution'. I'm wondering if there's something like that in Sun Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple Projects an group it (**`File -> Project Group -> New Group ...`**).
Is this what you need?

Here are two examples:

http://envyandroid.com/archives/142/project-groups-in-netbeans
http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/netbeans-ide-tip-1-project-groups/